# Perl script unable to open a file in write mode

Tags: file, perl, file-permissions, file-handling, filehandle

As I am new to Perl can anyone help me out with this code.
I want to write contents to a file named redirectedOutputFile (create one such file if it does not exist).

perlRedirect.pl

```
$var = @ARGV[0];

print "Hello!\n";


$filepath = "/tools/<some_location>/testdir1/redirectedOutputFile";
open(FILE_HANDLE, ">", $filepath) or die("$filepath: $!");

#system("chmod 777 redirectedOutputFile");
print FILE_HANDLE "Permissions given!\n";

foreach(1..$var){
    #print "Hi!\t";
    print FILE_HANDLE "$_\n";

}

print FILE_HANDLE "Done!\n";
```

When I execute the script using
`$ perl perlRedirect.pl 10`

I am getting the output :

```
/tools/<some_location>/testdir1/redirectedOutputFile: Permission denied at perlRedirect.pl line 14.
```

I want the script to create a new file if it does not exist and store the contents in the same file. Also, can I change permissions of redirectedOutputFile in this script? 
Thank you.

Comment: Change `die("Cannot open file")` to `die("Cannot open file ($!)")` and post the error message that is showed after the change.

Comment: ```$ perl perlRedirect.pl 10
Hello!
Cannot open file (Permission denied) at perlRedirect.pl line 14.
```
The error message after the change

Comment: That reveals that you (or rather the user the program runs under) has no right to either open the file (in write mode) or create it. Check the permissions of the file and/or the directory that should contain it.

Comment: It is more conventional to include the path in the error message.  eg `open my $fh, ">", $filepath or die "$filepath: $!";`

Comment: How can I grant permissions within this script? @stickybit

Comment: @Shreyaskar: You would change the file's permissions with the [chmod](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html) function. But if you don't have permission to write to the file, you might not have permission to change its permissions.

Comment: @DaveCross: Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: @Shreyaskar: You find the person who owns the file and ask them to change the permissions for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running the script with the help of `sudo` and it works fine!

I changed the execution line to 
`sudo perl perlRedirect.pl 5`

With this I got the output as:
`Hello!`